# Setting up bootstrap-vue with Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I made a fresh install of **Nuxt.js** with `bootstrap-vue/nuxt` module which was properly added to `nuxt.config.js`. But now, when I add an element like `<v-btn text>foo</v-btn>` to my index page, I get the following error message in the javascript console:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-btn> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <Nuxt>
         <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
           <Root>
```

How should I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<v-btn>` is not a `Bootstrap-Vue` component. `<b-button>` or `<b-btn>` is however.
You might be confusing [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons/#buttons) with [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/button/#buttons). Or maybe you just have a typo since `v` and `b` is right next to eachother.

Comment: Indeed, I was confusing Vuetify with Bootstrap-Vue. Thanks!